# Share javascript properties

Tags: javascript, properties, share

I have made a simple object

```
var myObject = {
formname: $('form'),
input: this.formname.find('input'),

init: function() {
    console.log(myObject.input)
}
```

}

myObject.init();

http://jsfiddle.net/t3fjffLg/

But this does not work. I want to use my name property in name2 property.
What is the best approach for sharing properties ?
Do I have to use prototype instead ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var myObject = {
    name: 'Johan',
    name2: function(){return this.name},

    init: function() {
        console.log(this.name2())
    }
}
```

Comment: it just seems a bit overkill to have a function, just to share a value.

Comment: @Johansrk I could be wrong but this seems like the easiest way to achieve what you asked. The alternative is as Hatem mentioned in terms of setting the property on initialization. What exactly are you trying to achieve? As name: "Johan", name2: this.name even if it worked seems like quite useless code.

Comment: It would just be nice to fx share a selector. See my edited code

Comment: @Johansrk Yeah, I would still simply wrap in a function and return. That would allow you to return the selector as you wish. I don't think it's an overkill as the alternatives are way messier.

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is to initialize the "name2" with the same value of "name". So, the best approach to do that is to make it inside " init " method:

```
var myObject = {
    name: 'Johan',
    name2: null,

    init: function() {
        this.name2 = this.name
        console.log(myObject.name2)
    }
}

myObject.init();
```

Or if you insist to assign the value of the property in the header. Then you have to follow this approach :

```
name2: function(){ return this.name }
```

Comment: this was just an example. I guess the question is, how to share properties accross an object ?